# Cannot change column names after converting dict to Pandas dataframe.

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, dataframe, rename

I am new to Python and Pandas. I am trying to convert a dictionary to a data frame. My original dictionary is a key followed by uneven length of list. 
The dict looks as below:

```
      {'PlaceA': [(1992, 2015)], 'PlaceB': [(1980, 1984), (1988, 1991)], 'PlaceC': [(1985, 1987)]}
```

To convert this to a df, I use

```
d = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(city_dict, orient='index')
```

It works fine and produce the resultant df as below:

```
                                     0                1
    PlaceA                     (1992, 2015)          None
    PlaceB                     (1980, 1984)    (1988, 1991)
    PlaceC                     (1985, 1987)          None
```

While I can rename column easily using

```
d.rename(columns={0:'new column name'})
```

I cannot rename the name of the first column (place name). I tried using

```
d.rename(columns={'':'place'}, inplace=True)
```

but it does not work. 
Strangely, when I tried to print out the header, I get the following output

```
print(list(d.columns.values))

[0, 1]
```

Is there anything I am missing out?

Your comments are greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That first 'column' isn't a column; it is the [index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#dataframe).  You can name it using:

```
df.index.name = 'Place Name'

                       0             1
Place Name                            
PlaceC      (1985, 1987)          None
PlaceB      (1980, 1984)  (1988, 1991)
PlaceA      (1992, 2015)          None
```

Or you can convert that index into a column using:

```
d = d.reset_index()
d.rename(columns={'index':'Place Name'}

  Place Name             0             1
0     PlaceC  (1985, 1987)          None
1     PlaceB  (1980, 1984)  (1988, 1991)
2     PlaceA  (1992, 2015)          None
```

Comment: Thanks so much Scott! It works now. I guess I still have a lot to learn about Python and Pandas.

Comment: @macintosh81 You are welcome.  Thank you for accepting.